# Passing value from screen to screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

**History** In my project I have about 30 different screens, to acquire data. 
Now what usually I have to pass values from one screen to another. ( Like UserID, StoreID, City, etc )

What I currently do to pass values. I keep doing for 30 screens.

```
//Sender Activity
String strValue  = "xyz";    
Intent i = new Intent(this, ToClass.class);
i.putExtra("strValue", strValue);
startActivity(i); 

//Receiving Activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
String strValue= intent.getExtras().getString("strValue");
```

Now my technical question is
a) The value in still alive (or uses memory) in the sender Activity. So how to I clear when moving to the next Activity?
b) Should it be better that I save `strValue` value in `DB` and access value from `DB` whenever I need? Hence saving my memory.
c) Is this the best approach in Android. What I'm currently using.

Comment: You can save data on your memory.It best way because when you clear  data remove that data.

Comment: saving in DB and retrieving will increase cpu overhead.

Comment: you can make a call to `finish()`, after you call `startActivity()`. An other option would be to point your values to `null`, if your activity is finishing. So in `onPause()` check if your activity is finishing http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing(), and do `strValue  = null;` Take a look at threads discussing `Java performance tuning`.

Answer (score 1):

a) leave the clearing of memory/data to GC it will take care of unused data in your memory.

b) if it is just a single value you don't want to put it in the `DB` simply because it will use a `memory` too and it will take much longer(in terms of `ms` i think / overhead) rather than passing it as a bundle or in sharedpreference

c) if you want your `strValue` to be alive only when the app is alive. that would be your approach. and if you want the `strValue` to be in the memory i assume it is only 1 value you could use [sharedpreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). and if you have so much data that you need to put in memory it is the time to use [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/).